# Understanding Matlab histcounts behavior

Tags: matlab, histogram

```
histcounts(1:100,'BinWidth',50)
```

returns

```
49    51
```

Why doesn't it return

```
50    50
```

instead?

Comment: probably because the bins are centered between the grid points, so you miss the 0.5 center between 0 and 1....   you probably want `histcounts(0:99,'BinWidth',50)`

Answer (score 1):

Histogramming 1 to 100 inclusive with `h = histogram(1:100, 'BinWidth', 50)` gives:

[image]

Let's see the bin edges:

```
h.BinEdges

ans =

     0    50   100
```

From [MATLAB's help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html#buhzm_z-1-edges):

> Each bin includes the left edge, but does not include the right edge,
>   except for the last bin which includes both edges

That means that values 1  to 100 are histogrammed in this format:

```
Bin 1 => edges: [0 50) => Included values: [1, 2, 3, .., 49]         (n = 49)
Bin 2 => edges: [50 100] => Included values: [50, 51, 52, .., 100]   (n = 51)
```

`histcount(X)` partitions `X` in the same manner as `histogram(X)`. Therefore, the results are what you should expect and in fact very reasonable.